# best way to have checkbox column in WPF datagrid with header checkbox (select all) and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, selectall

I was using *DevExpress* components, with selectall view.
because its hard to customize *DevExpress* style, I decide to use WPF default `DataGrid`.

what is the best way to have Select All checkbox in WPF DataGrid ?
there is no complete solution and/or working solution in the net.

I need to bind checkbox `IsChecked` to selected Items/Rows.
`SelectedItems` is readonly. so I used solution in

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html

but I am not sure how bind selected item to `IsChecked`, and MVVM.

do I need to add extra field for bool `SelectAll` in my model ?

please let me know your solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. You want a "master" `CheckBox` in each column to select all the CheckBoxes in that column? or a "Master" `CheckBox` to select all checkboxes in the `DataGrid`?